# Genitive case vs. Compound nouns?

Tags: meaning, usage, grammar-identification

The genitive case has many other functions other than expressing possession. One important function is to provide explanation, definition, or description. Another function is to indicate a quality or a feature. Compound nouns can be composed of two parts, where the second part is the main part and the first part acts as a modifier that specifies, determines, or qualifies the following part.

In the previous senses, what is the difference between the following expressions?

- Der Strahl der Hoffnung -- Der Hoffnungsstrahl
- Die Strafe der Verbannung -- Die Verbannungsstrafe
- Das Ticket erster Klasse -- Das Ersteklasseticket

Is it only a matter of how we understand the expression? For example, *Die Verbannungsstrafe* is a type of punishment considering we have a list of different kinds of punishments, while in *Die Strafe der Verbannung* I am describing here the type of punishment or explaining what kind of punishment it is. Just nuances in meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nein, es gibt keine Bedeutungsunterschiede, auch keine Nuancen.

Bei einem etablierten Wort wie "Himmelsstürmer" kann man gelernt haben, was es bedeutet, während man bei "Stürmer des Himmels" stockt, weil es ungebräuchlich ist. In beiden Fällen ergibt sich aber die Bedeutung nicht aus dem Genitiv oder der Zusammensetzung. Beides könnte auch einen Stürmer im Himmel oder vom Himmel bezeichnen.

Man kann übrigens auch "Strafverbannung" sagen, wobei es wohl wenige andere Verbannungsgründe gibt, vielleicht Präventivverbannung.

Richtig ist, dass in Zusammensetzungen der letzte Teil sagt, was es ist und der erste Teil differenziert.

- Ein Holztisch ist ein Tisch aus Holz im Gegensatz zum Glastisch oder Basttisch.
- Das Tischholz ist ein Holz für Tische, im Gegensatz zum Geigenholz und Brennholz.

Comment: Thank you. Is this the same reason why we use *Autogeschäft* instead of *Geschäft des Autos*? Simply because that the established and used term is the first one, and the second one though grammatically correct but not used and seems odd, or there might be another reason?

Comment: @Abdullah - Ein Muttersprachler würde, wenn er den seltsamen Ausdruck "Das Geschäft des Autos" hört, bei der verzweifelten Suche, was es heißen könnte, nur darauf kommen, dass hier ein Auto ein Geschäft abgeschlossen hat oder ein Geschäft betreibt. Für die Alltagsverwendung ist "das Geschäft des Autos" also so gut wie unbrauchbar.

Answer (score 1):

> Der Strahl der Hoffnung — Der Hoffnungsstrahl

This is a nice picture but the typical German expression for it is:

> Der Schimmer der Hoffnung — Der Hoffnungsschimmer

Both expressions are commonly used.

> Die Strafe der Verbannung — Die Verbannungsstrafe

Both possible and equally uncommon.

> Das Ticket erster Klasse — Das Erste-Klasse-Ticket

Both expressions are commonly used. Sometimes compounds are realized with hyphens, this is the usual case if a number, ordinal or name is part of the compound. (*Das Ticket* is a recent loanword, you may also hear *die Fahrkarte/die Eintrittskarte*.)

In general, genitive supplements are used to avoid creating compound words with just too many components, and for creating a slow pacing.

> Der Stürmer des Himmels — **Der Himmelsstürmer**

A *Stürmer* is fast. Slow pacing sounds just wrong. In addition, *des Himmels* may be misunderstood as *coming from heaven*. Instead, a *Himmelsstürmer* storms heaven.

> **Die Oase der Ruhe** — Die Ruheoase

Both an *Oase* and *Ruhe* are soothing. Fast pacing sounds just wrong.

Comment: Schimmer und Strahl sind aber nicht äquivalent. Ticket ist ziemlich recent, erst seit 1790 im Gebrauch zwischenzeitlich sprach man häufiger vom Billet. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Ticket%2CBillet%2CFahrkarte%2CEintrittskarte&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CTicket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBillet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CFahrkarte%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CEintrittskarte%3B%2Cc0 Ersteklasseticket ist vollkommen in Ordnung, auch wenn Du persönlich lieber Bindestriche hättest.

Comment: Ich denke, ich habe es eindeutig genug erklärt, dass Hoffnungsstrahl zwar ein schönes Bild ist, Hoffnungsschimmer aber der übliche Ausdruck im Deutschen. Für deinen Ausreißer von 1765 kannst du dir gar nichts kaufen. Damals gab's nichtmal 'ne Eisenbahn, und dass die Postkutsche da so in aller Munde war, dass sie den Textkorpus dominiert ist auch recht unwahrscheinlich. Und nein, wenn du Ersteklasseticket googlest (was du ja gerne zu tun scheinst), bekommst du als Ergebnisseiten praktisch nur Texte, die *Erste-Klasse-Ticket* enthalten.

Comment: I can deduce that in the senses mentioned above in my question, both compound nouns and genitive are completely interchangeable except for the established words? I mean, words that have been consistently used in one form in such a way other forms seem odd to native speakers.

Comment: Yes, they are interchangeable. It's mostly a matter of pacing. And sometimes, compound words can sound awkward even to German ears.

Comment: Keine Ahnung, ob das eventuell ein Regionalismus ist, aber bei Zusammenschreibung oder beim Hören würde ich eher ein Erste***r***klasseticket erwarten. Bei der Schreibweise mit Bindestrichen kommt mir aber Erste-Klasse-Ticket auch normaler vor.

Comment: Nach meinem Sprachverständnis bedeutet "but the typical German expression for it is" soviel wie "der typische, deutsche Ausdruck *dafür* ist". Zwar ist von Hoffnungsschimmern oft die Rede, von einem Hoffnungsstrahl dagegen selten, aber das macht den Schimmer doch nicht zu einem geeigneten Übersetzungskandidaten. Ein Schimmer ist etwas schwaches, amorphes und fragiles, ein Strahl dagegen deutlich, gebündelt und eher kräftig. "Wurstbrot" ist auch ein üblicher Ausdruck im Deutschen. -- Kann ich mir für das ganze 19. Jhrh. auch nichts kaufen? Sind das auch alles Ausreißer? Oder ist das "kürzlich"?

Comment: Du bist doch ganz aufgeweckt. Nimm einfach mal "Billet" und "Fahrkarte" zum Vergleich. Dann suchst du bitte die Texte auf, in denen **stattdessen** "Ticket" vorkommt. Ich bin auf das Ergebnis gespannt.

Comment: In Texten tritt ja normalerweise dies oder das auf. Wenn Billet vorkommt, dann kommt eben Billet vor und weder Fahrkarte noch Ticket. Und vice versa. Meinst Du etwas wie Marie Madelaine, Der rote Champion, "Fräulein von Nordstetten wandte sich von neuem dem hübschen Ulanenleutnant zu. »Bitte, Graf, besorgen Sie das Ticket. Wenn Sie es auch in Uniform nicht selbst dürfen, so kennen Sie gewiss Leute, die eins holen können.« (1910)

Comment: Oder 1914: "Die Vermutung im Publikum, daß die Beamten des Totalisateurs durch falsche Berechnungen oder Entnahme der Tickets nach abgelassenem Start während des Rennens die Gewinstquote vermindern, kommt wohl selten vor."

Comment: Zum Beispiel. Kommt dreimal im ganzen Buch vor, in dem eins der Pferde zudem noch *Queen Maud* heißt, ein anderes *Sweet Beast*. Zudem ist die ganze Pferderenngeschichte zu der Zeit natürlich mit englischem chic angehaucht. Das ist notweniger Kolorit in so einer Geschichte und spricht gerade gegen weitläufige Verwendung.

Comment: Einspruch. Es kann nicht gleichzeitig gängiger Chic sein und weitläufig unbekannt.  Wie auch Pferde mit englischem Namen nicht nach dem Gebrauch von "Ticket" dürsten. Statt von mir Beispiele einzufordern könntest Du mal näher umreißen, was Du im Zusammenhang "recent loanword" mit recent denn meinst. Seit der Wiedervereinigung, seit Internetzeiten - das ist ja immer noch offen. Oder sind wir tatsächlich bei 1910? Wir haben keinen Schimmer; Du würdest vielleicht sagen "keinen Strahl".

Comment: Seit es die Bahn selbst statt "Fahrkarte" benutzt. Das ist doch völlig logisch. Vielleicht zu einfach. Außerdem bist du doch mit meiner Antwort unzufrieden. Ist also alleinig deine Aufgabe, für dein Herummosern belastbare Gründe zu finden. Damit bist du krachend gescheitert – dafür kann ich nichts.

Answer (score 1):

I would translate your examples into English into a construction in a "possessive" sense, using the word "of." That would correspond to the genitive in German.

- Der Strahl der Hoffnung -- Der Hoffnungsstrahl. The ray *of* hope.
- Die Strafe der Verbannung -- Die Verbannungsstrafe. The penalty *of* a ban.
- Das Ticket erster Klasse -- Das Ersteklasseticket. The ticket of the first class (better translated as "the first class ticket").